# Laravel router returning error 500 internal-server-error

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, controller, router

When I make a javascript ajax request, console log a 500 error (internal-server-error)
I already pass an token to the request in headers with {{ csrf_token() }}
What I am making wrong?

My router setup

```
Route::post('/checkemail', 'UserController@checkemail');
```

My controller file

```
   <?php
      namespace App\Htpp\Controllers;

      use Illuminate\Http\Request;

      class UserController extends Controller{
         public function checkemail(Request $request){
            return 'something';   
         }
      }
    ?>
```

My javascript ajax

```
path = location.href
token = {{ csrf_token() }}

$.ajax({
        url: `${path}checkemail`,
        method: "post",
        data: {"email":email},
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
        }
    }).done(function(result){
       console.log(result)
   }
```

Comment: From your network console, check the header path. Is it making the right call? ${path}checkemail

Comment: yes it is making.
no 404 errors returning

Comment: Can you please share the errors with 500 status code

Comment: Send csrf token as part of your data.... Add.     "_token" : token

Comment: @nikistag I don't think it's an issue with csrf because csrf errors return 419 response not 500, and OP has a `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header in the request already, so no need to send it in the data

Comment: @JoãoPereira please share the error message so we can answer an accurate answer.

Comment: @Arun A S for post requests you need both csrf in header and as post request input. Laravel is checking for both. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: @nikistag, yes laravel checks in both header and in input, and if it finds a valid header or request input, then the request is valid, so you only need it in one of them. If you have csrf header, you don't need it in the request body. If you have `_token` in request body you don't need it in header. I use ajax all the time and I usually only add the header and it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are typing the correct `namespace` in the controller.

the `namespace` should be `App\Http\Controllers;` not `App\Htpp\Controllers;` (as in the route you typed `UserController` without prefixing it with the full namespace).

so the controller will be as below:

```
   <?php
      namespace App\Http\Controllers; // here is the change

      use Illuminate\Http\Request;

      class UserController extends Controller{
         public function checkemail(Request $request){
            return 'something';   
         }
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: That solve the problem :), thank you.
Do I need to close this question? where can I do that..

Comment: great that your problem is solved ! ... in order for you To accept an answer, click on the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons to the left of the answer that solved your problem, checkout this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png